# How to query for many to many relationship in Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

Here is my tables [image]

My question is How to get CourseNames for a specific student id

I tried this but didn't work

```
select Course.CourseName from Course
where Course.CourseId in (

select Student.studentname ,StudentCourse.CourseId from Student inner join StudentCourse
on Student.StudentId = StudentCourse.StudentId
  where Student.StudentId = 1)
```

You can forget my query because i am new in SQL Server just tell me what exactly developers do in SQL Server real-world to get course names of a specific student

Comment: This looks an awful lot like homework. You'll find that folks here will encourage you to figure this out on your own. You should start with what results you want for a specific StudentID, and then what results you get. coding, even SQL is iterative. You should be trying more than one thing, refining as you go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using left joins just in case your student doesn't have any courses assigned, otherwise, if you use inner joins, you'll get no results;

```
SELECT
s.StudentID
,s.StudentNam
,sc.CourseID
,c.CourseName
FROM Student s
LEFT JOIN StudentCourse sc
ON s.StudentID = sc.StudentID
LEFT JOIN Course c
ON sc.CourseID = c.CourseID
WHERE s.StudentID = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

As you said you want to know the approach this is just basic viewpoint

1) We want to look at CourseName's.

```
SELECT CourseName FROM Course
```

2) One Student may have more than one Courses.
3) So we have one more table which is StudentCourse to achieve this.
4) We have to look CourseName's ID'S in this table

```
SELECT CourseID FROM StudentCourse
```

5) to find which students(X is a number you seach for) takes those courses.

```
WHERE StudentID = X
```

6) If we look them together, we now have all CourseName's via step 1. But we don't want all CourseName's and we have all CourseID's which X numbered student takes. So if we get them together, now we will just select CourseName's which X takes.

```
WHERE CourseID IN
```

7) So our final result is

```
SELECT CourseName FROM Course WHERE CourseID IN 
(SELECT CourseID FROM StudentCourse WHERE StudentID = X)
```

### Check [this](http://ideone.com/vLFNeM) or [this one](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2acee/1) to see how it works.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
select CourseName from Course
where CourseId in 
(select CourseId from StudentCourse
where StudentId = 1)
```